# Initializing a char array through passed pointer segfaults

Tags: c++, arrays

Ie., why does the following work:

```
    char* char_array(size_t size){
            return new char[size];
    }

    int main(){
            const char* foo = "foo";
            size_t len = strlen(foo);
            char* bar=char_array(len);
            memset(bar, 0, len+1);
    }
```

But the following segfaults:

```
    void char_array(char* out, size_t size){
            out= new char[size];
    }

    int main(){
            const char* foo = "foo";
            size_t len = strlen(foo);
            char* bar;
            char_array(bar, len);
            memset(bar, 0, len+1);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [malloc memory to a pointer to pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210587/malloc-memory-to-a-pointer-to-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing 'bar' to char_array is passing a copy of the *present value of that pointer* at the time of the call - so 'out' in char_array points to the same thing as 'bar' but they're completely isolated variables, and when char_array returns the newly allocated value is simply lost.

If you want to actually modify the 'bar' variable, you need to pass a pointer or reference to the bar variable itself, i.e.

```
void char_array(char** out, size_t size) {
    *out = new char[size];
}

...
char_array(&bar, len);
```

or

```
void char_array(char*& out, size_t size) {
    out = new char[size];
}

...
char_array(bar, len);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not modifying `out`, you need to pass the pointer by reference:

```
void char_array(char*& out, size_t size)
//                   |
//           pass by reference
```

Right now you're calling `memset` on an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 0 void char_array(char* out, size_t size)
 1 {
 2    out = new char[size];
 3 }

 5 int main()
 6 {
 7    const char* foo = "foo";
 8    size_t len = strlen(foo);
 9    char* bar;
10    char_array(bar, len);
11    memset(bar, 0, len+1);
12 }
```

`char* bar` at line 9 is not initialised, so declares a pointer variable that can point anywhere.  Line 10 calls char_array, copying that garbage pointer value to the `out` parameter.  Note that it's the garbage value from within bar that's copied - `out` gets the value but has no inherent connection to `bar`.  This garbage value is never used - it's just overwritten with the pointer returned by `new` on line 2, then discarded as the function returns.

To allow `char_array` to change `bar` itself, either use a reference to a pointer:

```
void char_array(char*& out, size_t size) { out = new ... }
```

...or a pointer to a pointer...

```
void char_array(char** p_out, size_t size) { *p_out = new ... }

char_array(&bar, len);
```

Either way `char_array` knows where `bar` is to modify it.