# How do you properly allocate a struct inside a function?

Tags: c, function, malloc, pass-by-value

I have this code which is where I've narrowed down the problem. When I step through with the debugger it seems to be fine but as soon as it leaves the function, freeCount loses the value assigned to it. It is supposed to be 100, and until the last } it shows it assigned the value fine but as soon as the function breaks it goes back to some 16 digit value. Can anyone point out my error?? much appreciated!

```
   void initializeTree(TREE* empList)
   {
        empList = (TREE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE));
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= maxEmp; i++)
        {
            time_t seed = time(null);
            empList->freeList[i] = (int)(rand() % seed);
        }
        empList->freeCount = maxEmp;
        empList->parent = null;
        empList->root = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because in C arguments to functions are passed *by value*, which means they are *copied*. So when you pass a pointer to a function, the functions receives a *copy* of the pointer, and as you know changing a copy will not change the original.

C doesn't have argument passing *by reference*, but it can be emulated using pointers. So to pass a pointer by reference you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void initializeTree(TREE** empList)
{
    *empList = malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    ...
    (*empList)->freeCount = maxEmp;
    ...
}
```

To call this function you need to use the address-of operator `&`:

```
TREE *empList;
initializeTree(&empList);
```

---

Another alternative is to *return* the pointer:

```
TREE* initializeTree(void)
{
    TREE* empList = malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    ...
    return empList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that helps! but what if I don't make empList a pointer initially? `TREE empList; initializeTree(&empList);` instead of dealing with the double pointer. or do I NEED to make it a double pointer for it to work the way I want?

Comment: @PatrickDixon Then you have to remove the line `empList = (TREE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE));` from your function because you want to operate directly on the structure you gave the address of to the function instead of operating on a newly allocated one.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the value of empList in your function but it does not reach the caller. What you actually need to do is to pass in a pointer to a pointer of tree:

```
void initializeTree(TREE** empList)
{
    *empList = (TREE *)malloc(sizeof(TREE));
    [...]
}
```

You can also find more information (and other options) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210587/malloc-memory-to-a-pointer-to-pointer).